# Installing Intel's Fortran Compilers

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, intel-fortran, build-tools, intel-oneapi

I'm trying to install Intel's Fortran compiler toolset (the standalone installer not the entire OneAPI bundle) in a Windows 10 machine. I do not use Visual Studio or Visual Studio Build Tools and do not fancy installing them either. However my Intel Fortran compiler installation warned me that it will not work if I do not install Visual Studio or MSVC Build Tools.

I tried to install it ignoring the warnings and the OneAPI terminal did not show up in the Start Menu. I tried to manually activate the `setvars.bat` from an elevated command prompt, and got the activation echo message that goes like `Intel ...environment initialized...` and some more lines stating the tools and their versions. But when running `ifort` & `ifx` commands I got the `..is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` message.

So I decided to install the Build Tools for MS Visual Studio 2022 (Just the Build Tools core installation, around 90MiB download) without any additional workloads. Do I need to install any workloads for this? Am I missing something?

Then added it to PATH and tried reinstalling the compiler. I still got the IDE integration failed error message. This time I noticed that the `setvars.bat` required MS Visual Studio or Build Tools 2017 or 2019. So I went back, uninstalled the 2022 version and installed the 2019 version and tried reinstalling the compiler but it is still not working. I still get the `..is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` message. when running `ifx or ifort` even after manually running the `setvars.bat`.

Can anyone help me find a solution. I would really appreciate it. But as a temporary solution I installed MSYS2 toolset with gfortran compiler but I'm not satisfied. :(

Comment: You'll probably have better luck on the intel fortran compiler forum: https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/bd-p/fortran-compiler there's currently a bug with the latest version of visual studio, so you have to use 2019 (unless you can get a previous version of 2022, which I don't think you can for free). You do need the C++ desktop development workload installed https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/guide/installing-microsoft-visual-studio-2019-for-use-with-intel-compilers.html

Comment: there's also this relatively quick tutorial for if you want the compiler and nothing else: https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/The-Easy-and-Fast-Way-to-Install-JUST-Fortran-with-Intel-oneAPI/m-p/1360571#M160118